# Is there any documentation/release note available for each eclipse sphinx version released

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-emf, eclipse-sphinx

Not much information is available on the web related to sphinx framework and plugin development.
I searched in the official website but couldn't find anything specific. I would like to enhance my knowledge in Eclipse Modelling Framework and sphinx. Thanks in advance and your help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: The meta information about the Eclipse Sphinx project can be found here: https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/automotive.sphinx (see also the [Getting Started](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Sphinx/tutorials) link). Your question is too general for Stack Overflow. Please follow the tutorial and if you get stuck [show your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).